# The Question "Prove that there is no homomorphism from Z16 ⊕ Z2 onto Z4 ⊕ Z4" In texbook, Is my proof correct?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Assume，φ: Z16 ⊕ Z2 → Z4 ⊕ Z4, φ is HOMO. onto.
|Z16 ⊕ Z2| = |Z16||Z2| = 32 > 16 = |Z4||Z4| = |Z4 ⊕ Z4|
⇒
∃(a,b),(c,d) ∈ Z16 ⊕ Z2, (a,b) ≠ (c,d), φ((a,b)) = φ((c,d))
⇒
φ((a,b) + (c,d)) = φ((a + c, b + d)) =
2φ((a,b)) = φ(2(a,b)) = φ((2a,2b)) =
2φ((c,d)) = φ(2(c,d)) = φ((2c,2d))
⇒
a + c = 2a, b + d = 2b,
a + c = 2c, b + d = 2d,
⇒
a = c, b = d
⇒
(a,b) = (c,d)（contradiction）

Comment: Consider the fact that there is a very simple onto homomorphism from $\Bbb Z_{16}\oplus \Bbb Z_2$ onto $\Bbb Z_8\oplus \Bbb Z_2$. But I suspect your proof would say that there isn't.

Comment: Your post would look so much better if you would spend some time with https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Wrong implication: "⇒  
a + c = 2a, b + d = 2b,  
a + c = 2c, b + d = 2d, "

Comment: Is a = c, b = d actually means a ≡ c mod 16, b ≡ d mod 2? so can't prove it's contradication?

Comment: And why does "assume" start with small letter while you can obviously use capital letters?

Comment: I'm sorry about my pool english :(

Comment: I do not understand how your comment "Is a = c, b = d actually means a ≡ c mod 16, b ≡ d mod 2? so can't prove it's contradication?" answers Arthur's or mine. Please review your proof.

Comment: As Arthur and Anne have explained, this proof is not correct. You seem to assume non-injectivity, and seek to derive a result that would show the homomorphism to be injective after all. That is A) impossible, and B) does not prove the claim which is about the non-existence of a surjective homomorphism. If you could arrive at this kind of a contradiction, you would be able to conclude that there are no homomorphisms at all, but that is clearly false. Hint: Show that anything that is a multiple of four is necessarily in the kernel, and then use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: I think you means  φ is not 1-1, so the implication: "⇒ a + c = 2a, b + d = 2b, a + c = 2c, b + d = 2d, " is wrong?

Comment: I think I got where is wrong, I just think φ is well-defined, but only injective, the contrapositive of x ≠ y ⇒ φ(x) ≠ φ(y) can got the implication

Comment: @navigatorX You don't have to use double paranthesis. Recall that in calculus we write functions of two variables like $f(x,y)$ not like $f((x,y))$.

Comment: sorry for my lack of information. Is this direct sum notation?

Answer (score 1):

I am not pure algebraist mathematician, but I thought an ideal solution would be in the following way:

If $φ$ is onto, ${\rm Ker}(φ)<\Bbb{Z}_{16}\oplus\Bbb Z_2$ is a normal subgroup of order $\frac{16\times 2}{4\times 4}=2$. So, we have $3$ cases:

i) ${\rm Ker}(φ)=\Bbb Z_2\oplus 0$ in which case ${\rm Im}(φ)\cong\frac{\Bbb{Z}_{16}\oplus\Bbb Z_2}{\Bbb Z_2\oplus 0}\cong\Bbb{Z}_{8}\oplus\Bbb Z_2$,

ii) ${\rm Ker}(φ)=0\oplus\Bbb Z_2$ in which case ${\rm Im}(φ)\cong\frac{\Bbb{Z}_{16}\oplus\Bbb Z_2}{0 \oplus \Bbb Z_2}\cong\Bbb{Z}_{16}$,

iii) ${\rm Ker}(φ)=D$, the diagonal $\Bbb Z_2$ in which case ${\rm Im}(φ)\cong\frac{\Bbb{Z}_{16}\oplus\Bbb Z_2}{D}\cong\Bbb{Z}_{16}$ again.

Contradiction.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks. Diagonal is really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I think OP is seeking for an elemantry proof which uses only definition of HOMO. and some modular arithmetic avoiding some isomorphism theorems, kernels or quotients, etc.

As pointed out J. Lahtonen, by definition of group homomorphism, we notice that $$\phi(4a,4b)=4\phi(a,b)=(0,0).$$ Hence, we reach the important conclusion that $\phi(0,0)=\phi(4,0)=\phi(8,0)=\phi(12,0)=(0,0).$ Then, we conclude that the image is determined by the elements $$\{(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)\}\subset\Bbb Z_{16}\oplus\Bbb Z_2$$ and the image can contain at most $8$ elements. Contradiction.

Comment: In my new answer I used the letter $\phi$ instead of OP's phi.